# Cordova InAppBrowser Top Margin

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, cordova-plugins

i'm trying to customize the Cordova InAppBrowser to add a top margin in the webView.

I would like to use the in app browser but showing at the top of the screen a 50px navigation bar with a back button to close the InAppBrowser.

Currently working with the iOS version, i'm trying to change the origin of the view to y = 50, but it's not working.

`CGRect theFrame = self.inAppBrowserViewController.view.frame;
 theFrame.origin.y = 50;
 theFrame.size.height = theFrame.size.height - 50;
 self.inAppBrowserViewController.view.frame = theFrame;`

It always leave me free space at the bottom of the view.

Comment: There's [a ticket open for that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3397) but it seems it's not a big prio for Cordova core team (however it seems a number of people would like to have the feature, exactly in order to display the header/footer)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28433766/245966

Answer (score 3):

I found out Cordova-OverAppBrowser is doing the job quite well, at least for Android https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-OverAppBrowser (OSX is supported, but I did not tested it, yet).

You can create a new browser and specify X, Y, width and height. Last parameter is a fade in animation:

```
var oab = new OverAppBrowser($stateParams.input, 0, 50, 400, 400, true);
```

If you are using ionic, make sure to close the browser window when leaving the view:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
    oab.close();
});
```

Fetching it directly from github was the only working solution for me:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/etabard/Cordova-OverAppBrowser
```

Answer (score 1):

you should set toolbar=yes when opening window and get what you need

```
window.open(url, _blank, 'toolbar=yes');
```

Comment: This is just opening the InAppBrowser fullscreen as usual, with the toolbar. But i would like to add a top margin to show the original view of my application.

Answer (score 1):

See rePositionViews

```
- (void) rePositionViews {
    if ([_browserOptions.toolbarposition isEqualToString:kInAppBrowserToolbarBarPositionTop]) {
        [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.toolbar.frame.origin.x, [self getStatusBarOffset], self.toolbar.frame.size.width, self.toolbar.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

This method gets called following createViews to reset positions. This is where your changes got reset. Notice the line

```
[self.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.toolbar.frame.origin.x, [self getStatusBarOffset], self.toolbar.frame.size.width, self.toolbar.frame.size.height)];
```

You see that it's actually adding a top margin to address iOS 7's status bar height. Take advantage of that and offset it a bit more.