# cordova phonegap using external web page in app while maintaining header/footer (for navigation)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, iframe, cross-platform

So far I have tried inappbrowser and iframes.  Iframes work, but I have encountered a couple of app-breaking bugs in the implementation I am using with iframes.  Is there a more native-like solution for displaying external web pages inside of phonegap while still maintaining your apps navigation, such as a header with a side scrolling menu?

Comment: I think you can achieve it with https://github.com/Microsoft/ace

Comment: Very interesting.  I see that it also adds the ability to use widgets.  Have you used this kit in a production app?  Also have you integrated it with ionic at all?

Comment: @TrevorPanhorst can you have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser Also i suggest you to have a look at this link for more info on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433766/maintaining-header-when-opening-link-in-inappbrowser

Comment: @TrevorPanhorst I try to make some complex structures on Android and is a little bit buggy, but in your case to use only the webview element it could work. And I dont like ionic, i prefer to use Cordova alone.

Comment: As @Gandhi said I had a similar situation as yours and we decided to give themablebrowser a try. It did work great for us.

Comment: @TrevorPanhorst Did you tried out themablebrowser plugin? DId it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the easiest approach is to go with cordova themablebrowser plugin which simplifies the implementation and helps in ease of development and maintenance. You can have a look at [themablebroswer plugin link](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) for more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe you are right.  This seems to be the best hope for achieving this functionality in Ionic 1.

Comment: This, unfortunately, was not the answer I was looking for, and the other guy's answer suggesting something outside of Ionic definitely was not what I was looking for.  I went ahead and accept this answer because I feel as if there just isn't a perfect solution here and this is the closest.

Comment: @Trevor Thanks for the update and acceptance. Bit unfortunate to miss out on the bounty though :( happy coding. Cheers

Comment: Yeah apologies for the bounty.  I guess I wasn't 100%  on how that worked.  After a time limit it gives it to the only answer?  That guy put a non-related answer up just to get the bounty.  Seems like a bad system.

Comment: @TrevorPanhorst Oh that sounds a flaw in system. Hope to get it sometime. Thanks for your time :(

Comment: @TrevorPanhorst Hope you set one more bouty sometime :)